# Verificar se um input foi carregado com jQuery

Tags: jquery, front-end, input, dom, load

Preciso verificar se um input text foi carregado na página e checar se ele está preenchido, como posso fazer isso? Já tentei $('input').on('load') mas não funciona, e a forma que o script está feito não consigo fazer um $(document).ready. Quem souber uma solução, por favor manda aí

Comment: Qual a sua dúvida?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que o que você quer fazer é isto:

Faça um teste removendo o valor de value e depois removendo o input da página!

Como o teste será feito no carregamento da página, para fazer esses testes. Copie o código e teste na sua máquina!

```js
var inputText = $('#teste').val();
if( inputText !== undefined) {
  
  if ( inputText != '' ) {
    alert('Foi carregado e está preenchido !');
  } else {
    alert('Foi carregado e não está preenchido!');  
  }
} else {
 alert('Não foi carregado!');      
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="texto teste" id="teste" />
```

Comment: Boa, isso me ajudou. Valeu

Comment: Se era isso que você queria então marque a resposta como certa! ;)